# How to filter deleted user while listing inactive users via Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: active-directory, azure-logic-apps, microsoft-graph-api

In a Logic App, when I call Microsoft Graph API (https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users) as shown below in order to get inactive users with very old login dates (signInActivity/lastSignInDateTime) in AD,
MS graph returns inactive user lists including deleted users.

```
{
"uri": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users",
"method": "GET",
"queries": {
    "$count": "true",
    "$filter": "signInActivity/lastSignInDateTime le 2020-04-26T05:20:40.3214119Z",
    "$select": "id,userType,displayName,externalUserState,externalUserStateChangeDateTime,createdDateTime,signInActivity",
    "$top": "999"
},
"headers": {
    "ConsistencyLevel": "eventual"
},
"authentication": {
    "audience": "https://graph.microsoft.com/",
    "identity":XXX,
    "type": "ManagedServiceIdentity"
}
```

}

I want to get only non-deleted inactive users in AS via MS graph. I have followed steps from [here](https://www.expiscornovus.com/2022/03/04/list-inactive-users-via-graph-api/)

How can I get only only non-deleted inactive users? or

Is there any property as flag showing "Deleted" status in MS Graph Call Response?

Answer (score 0):

- Though the user is been removed/deleted from AAD, It is not always the case that user accounts get deleted. The user's activities will still be reflected because the user was once registered within the time period chosen.
- One workaround is to handle all those accounts by removing all its licenses.

**REFERENCES:**

1. [How to manage inactive user accounts in Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/reports-monitoring/howto-manage-inactive-user-accounts)
2. [Microsoft 365 admin center SharePoint activity report](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/activity-reports/sharepoint-activity-ww?view=o365-worldwide)

Comment: Is it possible to remove its licenses via Microsoft Graph? If so, which endpoint should I use? tx